# Is there any directive called ng-int? What is wrong with my ng-init syntax?

Tags: angularjs, ng-init

I want to initialize an angular variable with local scope *BWCount*.

When i use **ng-init** I get the following error
[Error: $parse:syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7BLastMonthTotal%3D(oCurrentDepartment.oMeter%5B0%5D.METER_READ)%7D%7D&p4=%7BLastMonthTotal%3D(oCurrentDepartment.oMeter%5B0%5D.METER_READ)%7D%7D)

But when I use ng-int (It was a typo, but turns out to be a surprising serendipity), it works fine and I can even use that variable in other markups.

What is happening here? Am I using the incorrect syntax for ng-init? And what is this ng-int (*I don't have any custom directive called ngInt*)

I am using Visual studio 2013 and have have the following markup:

```
<div ng-int="{{BWCount=(oCurrentDepartment.oMachineAccount|sumByKey:'BWCOUNT')}}">{{BWCount}}</div>
```

Notice `ng-int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-init` expects an angular expression, so you must not have `{{ }}` around it.

Your code works simply because angular considers `ng-int` as a basic HTML attribute, and evaluates the expression surrounded by `{{ }}` at each digest cycle. Not just at initialization.

`ng-init` should be avoided anyway. That code should be in your controller.