# Ng-click affecting an ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I attempted a 5 star rating system. Here is a simplified version my code:
https://codepen.io/ystaum/pen/NWbLoPO

HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="star in ctrl.range" ng-init="rated = star.id">      
        <button ng-repeat="num in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-class="{'blue':num <= rated}" ng-click="rated = num">{{ num }}</button>   
        </div>
      </body>
```

CSS:

```
 .blue{
        background:blue;
    }
```

JS:

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module("app", [])
        .controller("Controller", function ($http) {
            var vm = this;
      
            init();

            function init() {
                vm.rating = 3;
                
                vm.range = [{id:4},{ id:5},{id:0},{id:3}];
            };
        });
})();
```

The problem is that if you click on any button, just that button 'highlights' (if was not before). The way I set up the ng-class on the button should affect all buttons in that row (lower numbers 'highlighted, higher numbers not).
Why is this not doing that?
How do I make it do what I want?

Edited: The reason i used a var, was so i can keep the id value consistent, andto have the rating system show your choice in rating.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize [rated] var

try

```
 <div ng-repeat="star in ctrl.range" >      
        <button ng-repeat="num in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-class="{'blue':num <= star.id}" ng-click="star.id = num">{{ num }}</button>   
   </div>
```

Comment: thank you. 
this does work, but i guess i should have added that this was what i was trying to avoid. 
original code involved an http request, and i wanted to replace the data with a var, so i would not have to change the value at it core.

Comment: you can use ng-int out of ng-repeat to make it global for all items

Comment: whats ng-int? do you have a link to explain? couldn't find on my own

Comment: found this:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085749/is-there-any-directive-called-ng-int-what-is-wrong-with-my-ng-init-syntax> 
and replaced ng-init with ng-int="{{ curRating = things.ratings }}". got the same problem.